# Switch between front and back camera

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I'm trying to make a custom cameraView, which works so far. However i've reached an issue with switching between front and back camera. I've tried to handle it through a custom enum. However when the `switchCamera` method is called. it just seem to freeze the camera? How come is that?

**Camera Variable**

```
var camera = CameraType.Back
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
    switchButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(rightButtonXPoint, 35, 30, 30))
    switchButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Switch"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    switchButton.addTarget(self, action: "switchCamera", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    actionView.addSubview(switchButton)
```

**ViewWillAppear**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    reloadCamera()


}
```

**SwitchCamera**

```
func switchCamera() {

    if camera == CameraType.Back {
        camera = CameraType.Front
    } else {
        camera = CameraType.Back
    }
    reloadCamera()
}
```

**ReloadCamera**

```
func reloadCamera() {

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()


   // let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice! = nil
    if (camera == CameraType.Front) {
        let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        for device in videoDevices{
            let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {
                captureDevice = device
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    }

    do {
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

        if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil){

            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) != nil){
                captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

                previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                captureSession?.startRunning()

            }

            cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(actionView)
            previewImageView.bringSubviewToFront(actionView)
            self.previewImageView.hidden = true


        }
    }







}
```

Comment: I don't see where you ever call `switchCamera`, so where does the problem actually arise? Do you just call it smack in the middle of while a capture is going on already? If so, that's your problem; it's an incoherent thing to do.

Comment: I've added a button to the view which calls the `switchCamera`. I've added the code now

Comment: Okay, but as I said before, you can't just wantonly rip out the running capture session and replace it like that. You are not stopping the session. You are not replacing the preview layer in the interface. It's incoherent.

Comment: Okay so what am i suppose to do then? when can i call it?

Comment: You need to stop and think. If there there is already a running session, you need to stop it and take it down in good order, and you need to remove its layer from the interface.

Comment: ooh so i should remove the running capure session before?

Comment: Thank you however even though i set `captureSession?.stopRunning()` and
`previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()` it still does not seem to work. Now it just return a white screen with no camera?

Comment: That's better than freezing, though. :)

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing the exact specifics, it's hard to guess, but looking at your code, I think the problem you're running into is that you're trying to add more than one camera to the session (each time you switch, you're actually trying to add a new device).

Test to see if the capture session is running, then if it is, then REMOVE the existing device (back / front camera) before adding the new device.  Make sure you wrap it as a transaction like so:

```
func beginSession(captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?) {        

    if captureSession.running {
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        let currentInput : AVCaptureInput = captureSession.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureInput
        captureSession.removeInput(currentInput)

        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        } catch {
            print("Error adding video input device")
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()

    } else {
        // Setup the camera and layer for the first time.
        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
        } catch {
            print("Error adding video input device")
        }


        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, atIndex: 0)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

This is a fairly simple, but functional example.  I just pass the capture device in each time (Front / Back camera as needed) and it works well enough in my code.  Very prototype implementation, but hopefully this gives you the missing steps:

1. .beginConfiguration() BEFORE changing a running session.
2. Remove the existing device then add the new one.
3. .commitConfiguration() to make it all work.

No need to remove the preview layer as it's already hooked up to your currentSession anyway.