# how to toggle camera from back to front in the camera view View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a camera view like instagram when making a post by capture the image from our camera, I follow along this tutorial in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O8WBZNIAN8&t=64s

here is the code used :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var cameraPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    var image: UIImage?

    var toggleCameraGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

    var zoomInGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    var zoomOutGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        captureSession.startRunning()

        toggleCameraGestureRecognizer.direction = .up
        toggleCameraGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchCamera))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(toggleCameraGestureRecognizer)

        // Zoom In recognizer
        zoomInGestureRecognizer.direction = .right
        zoomInGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(zoomIn))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(zoomInGestureRecognizer)

        // Zoom Out recognizer
        zoomOutGestureRecognizer.direction = .left
        zoomOutGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(zoomOut))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(zoomOutGestureRecognizer)
        styleCaptureButton()
    }


    func styleCaptureButton() {
        cameraButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        cameraButton.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cameraButton.clipsToBounds = true
        cameraButton.layer.cornerRadius = min(cameraButton.frame.width, cameraButton.frame.height) / 2
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }

    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }
        currentDevice = backCamera
    }

    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {

            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput!.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)


        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer() {
        self.cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.frame

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
    }


    @objc func switchCamera() {
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        // Change the device based on the current camera
        let newDevice = (currentDevice?.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) ? frontCamera : backCamera

        // Remove all inputs from the session
        for input in captureSession.inputs {
            captureSession.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureDeviceInput)
        }

        // Change to the new input
        let cameraInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do {
            cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newDevice!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
        }

        currentDevice = newDevice
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }

    @objc func zoomIn() {
        if let zoomFactor = currentDevice?.videoZoomFactor {
            if zoomFactor < 5.0 {
                let newZoomFactor = min(zoomFactor + 1.0, 5.0)
                do {
                    try currentDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
                    currentDevice?.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: newZoomFactor, withRate: 1.0)
                    currentDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func zoomOut() {
        if let zoomFactor = currentDevice?.videoZoomFactor {
            if zoomFactor > 1.0 {
                let newZoomFactor = max(zoomFactor - 1.0, 1.0)
                do {
                    try currentDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
                    currentDevice?.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: newZoomFactor, withRate: 1.0)
                    currentDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Preview_Segue" {
            let previewViewController = segue.destination as! PreviewViewController
            previewViewController.image = self.image
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Preview_Segue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

i just want to change the function of change/ toggle camera from back camera to front camera or vice versa, at that code toggle camera occurred when we swipe up the view (by using gesture recognizer), but i want to change that toggle action by using button, so after the user pressed a button it will change from back camera to front camera or vice versa

i thought that i just move the code in  @objc func switchCamera() to @IBaction, but after i did pressed the button, after switching from front to back **the camera capture the image by itself**  and I can't get the image

to be honest i don't really grasp the code, so i need your help to edit the toggle action, how can i do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between front and back camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637566/switch-between-front-and-back-camera)